# My Application Crashes While Reloading table data

Tags: uitableview

My Application Crashes when it reloads UITableView data in ViewDidAppear . It works fine till the number of entries in table is less than 20 but once it goes above that it Crashes where Ever and whenever i call

```
    [tableview reloadData];
```

Comment: show cellForRowAtIndexPath. the crash is most likely there

Comment: How do you expect us to help you with only that information?

Comment: Error message? Stack trace? Anything?

Comment: are you really doing time pass here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly a discrepancy between the value returned from the [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method:

[`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3anumberOfRowsInSection%3a)

and the call to:

[`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a)

Where `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning more rows than `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` can provide.

However you don't provide enough information to help further.